# Why does while(std::ifstream >> s) work?

Tags: c++, stl

I've used statements such as this quite a bit in my C++ programming:

```
std::string s;
std::ifstream in("my_input.txt");
if(!in) {
    std::cerr << "File not opened" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
while(in >> s) {
    // Do something with s
}
```

What I want to know is, why does this work?

I looked at the return value of `operator>>`, and it's an `istream` object, not a boolean. How does an istream object somehow get interpreted as a bool value that can be put inside of `if` statements and `while` loops?

Comment: It does not have to *be* a `bool` it just needs to have an *implicit conversion* to `bool`. For example, any of the following are "falsy": `0`, `nullptr`, `0x0`, `false`, etc.

Comment: Hmm I see. How can you tell which classes have an implicit conversion to bool?

Comment: As @JosephMansfield mentioned, the class must have `operator bool()` defined.

Comment: @bobroxsox By reading the documentation of the class.  If a class is meant to be used as a boolean, then this fact will be clearly documented.  (For various historical reasons, the conversion to "bool" may be an `operator void*`, or even a conversion operator to some unknown pointer type, rather than an `operator bool`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The base class `std::basic_ios` provides an `operator bool()` method that returns a boolean representing the validity of the stream. For example, if a read reached the end of file without grabbing any characters, then `std::ios_base::failbit` will be set in the stream. Then `operator bool()` will be invoked, returning `!fail()`, at which time extraction will stop because the condition is false.

A conditional expression represents an explicit boolean conversion, so this:

```
while (in >> s)
```

is equivalent to this

```
while (static_cast<bool>(in >> s))
```

which is equivalent to this

```
while ((in >> s).operator bool())
```

which is equivalent to

```
while (!(in >> s).fail())
```

Comment: Of course, in pre-C++11, it wasn't `operator bool`, but `operator void*`.  But the effect was the same, since `void*` converts implicitly to `bool`.

Answer (score 5):

`std::basic_ios`, from which the input and output streams inherit, has the conversion function [`operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) (or `operator void*` prior to C++11 to get around the [safe-bool problem](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Safe_bool), which is no longer an issue thanks to the `explicit` keyword).

Answer (score 3):

See [std::basic_ios::operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

> This operator makes it possible to use streams and functions that return references to streams as loop conditions, resulting in the idiomatic C++ input loops such as `while(stream >> value) {...}` or `while(getline(stream, string)){...}`. Such loops execute the loop's body only if the input operation succeeded.