# how does while(std::ifstream >> char >> int) work? (again)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how the following while loop works:

```
//...
ifstream inf(filename);
char command;
int value;
//...
 while(inf >> command >> value)
  {
    if (command == 'i')
        list.insert(value,listItr);
        else
            list.remove(value);
  }
```

I read the answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505276/why-does-whilestdifstream-s-work) and understand how the while loop condition returns a bool. But I'm confused on how the `command` and `value` variables are assigned.
The file being read looks like this:

```
Has a series of 250,000 insertions in order from 1 to 250000
i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 i12 i13 i14 i15 i16 i17 i18 i19 i20 i21 i22 i23 i24 i25...
```

I figured the while condition would succeed only when reading i1 i2 etc. However, the loop gets past the first line of the file. Does the condition return true as long as any characters are read, regardless if they were mapped to variables?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you were expecting to happen, and how that differs from what actually happened.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/pXyRd0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [stream operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/):

```
istream& operator>> (bool& val);
^^^^^^^^
istream& operator>> (short& val);
^^^^^^^^
...
```

You'll see that all its versions return an `istream&`. So, once `inf >> command` has been executed, the resulting `istream` will be used to read data into `value`. This is kind of like equivalent to run `inf >> command`, and then `inf >> value`.

After that, the reason why you are able to run the loop is simple. The last read (`inf >> value`) does also return an `istream&`. And `istream` has the [bool operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) implemented. Therefore, you can "automatically" check if the `istream` still has data to be read.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Still adjusting to C++ and its dense syntax. Sometimes I'm lost on what to look for in the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> the loop gets past the first line of the file. Does the condition return true as long as any characters are read, regardless if they were mapped to variables?

No - you'll get `false` as soon as the parsing to variables fails.  The `inf >> command >> value` code can set `inf` into a `fail` state, after which the conversion to boolean will cause the `while` loop to terminate.  `fail` indicates inability to parse the input characters to form a value of the requested type.

By default, `istream` and its derivatives skip whitespace when using `>>`, so the `>> command` aspect requests the next non-whitespace character: any such character will be accepted.  `>> value` is different though: it will only succeed if the value encountered can be parsed as a number: it may optionally start with `-` or `+`, it must have at least one digit (`'0'`-`'9'`), but not so many that it's out of range for the destination type.

If the input contains something like say `i1E6`, that would be parsed as `command` `i`, `value` `1` followed by `command` `E`, `value`6`: i.e. the`E` doesn't introduce a power-of-ten exponent the way it does for floating point numbers.

Only errors in which there's not even one numeric digit at the point `value` is expected will be reported.  You could improve on this by rejecting values of `command` other than `i` and say `e`, `r` or `d` for erase, remove or delete....